# Binding Javascript to DOM elements when PartialView returns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am fairly new to the world of ASP.NET MVC 3  though I've already had some experience with it.
I am trying to achieve a functionality that goes as follows:

1. Make an AJAX call to some MVC controller that returns an HTML snippet
2. On return of that snippet I would like to bind some JavaScript (jQuery) events to its elements

The way I see it I have some options to resolve it:

1. Return a script block that binds those elements to the events: I'd rather not use since I want to make all script blocks tags in one central place.
2. Write a JavaScript function and call it once the AJAX call returns successfully. While that may be nice and clean, if I make that same AJAX call in different places in the code I'd have to write that function's name in every call (seems silly to me..)

To perfect the 2nd option I might use an HTML helper that will generate the AJAX call.

Is there some best practice that I am missing here?

If something remains unclear, please comment and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks.